# Why this is not working that way?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, facebook, navigation

I am trying to achieve Facebook like page navigation using AJAX. I have written following code.

```
if ("onhashchange" in window) {
    window.onhashchange = function () {
        locationChanged(window.location.href);
    }
}
else {
    var storedURL = window.location.href;
    window.setInterval(function () {
        if (window.location.href != storedURL) {
            storedURL = window.location.href;
            locationChanged(storedURL);
        }
    }, 250);
}

function locationChanged(e) {
    if (window.location.href.include('#!')) {
        var paths = window.location.href.split("#!");
        if (paths.length >= 2) {
            var pos = paths.length - 1;

            if (paths[pos].startsWith("/"))
                paths[pos] = paths[pos].substr(1);

            $('#holder').load(paths[pos]);
        }
    }
    else {
        if (window.location.href.endsWith('Index.html')
        || !window.location.href.endsWith('.html')) {
            //this is first page
            redirect("Login.html");
        }
    }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    if (window.location.href.endsWith('Index.html')
    || !window.location.href.endsWith('.html')) {
        //this is first page
        redirect("Login.html");
    }

    captureLinks();
});

function captureLinks() {
    $('a').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        redirect($(this).attr("href"));
    });
}

function redirect(page) {
    var path = page;

    if (window.location.href.include('#!')) {
        var paths = window.location.href.split("#!");

        var pos = paths.length - 2;

        if (!paths[pos].endsWith("/"))
            paths[pos] += "/";

        if (!page.startsWith("/"))
            page = "/" + page;

        path = paths[pos] + "#!" + page;
    }
    else {
        if (path.endsWith(".html"))
            path = window.location.href.trimEndTill("/");
        else
            path = window.location.href;

        if (!path.endsWith("/"))
            path += "/";

        if (!page.startsWith("/"))
            page = "/" + page;

        path += "#!" + page;
    }

    window.location.href = path;    
}
```

The good point is that the code is working but it has an only issue. There is an Index.html page which is the main entry page of the app and when I write say...

http://localhost:8081/

It converts it to...

http://localhost:8081/#!/Login.html

Which is perfect. But when I point it to say...

http://localhost:8081/Index.html

It was making it...

http://localhost:8081/Index.html/#!/Login.html

That was creating 404 error as there is no page named "Index.html/". I modified the code so it could detect Index.html and remove it first before pointing it to Login.html. Although the code gives the correct result now even with Index.html as...

http://localhost:8081/#!/Login.html

But the problem is, it never load that page (Login.html) in the body using $.load function. Is there anything wrong? I would also like to know if my code is efficient enough?

Comment: I am utilizing $.string jquery object so please ignore some functions like include, startsWith, endsWith and the like.

Comment: So you know, this is a terrible way to build a website. Anybody with JS turned off will be unable to do anything.

Comment: I know it. This is not a issue for now. I have another version which is AJAX less.

Comment: @Umair Ashra: [address plugin](http://www.asual.com/jquery/address/) ?

Comment: I tried thrice, it's not working

Comment: Please try to add contextual subject lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you actually need is the [jQuery Address plugin](http://www.asual.com/jquery/address/docs/). ([samples](http://www.asual.com/jquery/address/samples/))